# Syntax error in where clause in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

```
 fl=s.executeUpdate("
insert into demi(rno,subcode,subname,intm,extm,crd,resultdate)
values(
  '13JG1A05A0',
  'RT22058',
  ' FREE OPEN SOURCE SOFTWARE(FOSS) LAB ',
  '20',
  '70',
  '2',
  'MAY 2015'
)
end where not exists(SELECT * FROM demi WHERE rn0 ='13JG105A0' AND subcode='RT22058')
");
```

I'm working in jsp with postgresql as backend, my IDE shows error in this statement.
i want to insert a record into db after checking and making sure that no such record already exists

Is this statement correct, or am I trying a garbage code?

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: => `end where not exists`  should probably be `AND where not exists`.

Comment: `end where not exists` should be `where not exists`

Comment: An `insert` has no where clause.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error message is that an `INSERT` statement does not allow a `WHERE` clause.

You can only add a `where` clause to a `SELECT` statement (or a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statement)

So you would need to get rid of the `VALUES` clause and use the `insert into .. select ...` syntax:

```
insert into demi(rno,subcode,subname,intm,extm,crd,resultdate)
select '13JG1A05A0',
       'RT22058',
       ' FREE OPEN SOURCE SOFTWARE(FOSS) LAB ',
       '20',
       '70',
       '2',
       'MAY 2015'
where not exists (SELECT * 
                  FROM demi 
                  WHERE rn0='13JG105A0' 
                    AND subcode='RT22058');
```

---

However for the intended use case:

> I'm trying to insert a particular record into db if and only if there exists no other record with same rno and subject code columns

there is a better alternative if you have a unique constraint on `(rno, subcode)` (which you should) - use the `on conflict` clause:

```
insert into demi (rno, subcode, subname, intm, extm, crd, resultdate)
values
 (
  '13JG1A05A0',
  'RT22058',
  ' FREE OPEN SOURCE SOFTWARE(FOSS) LAB ',
  '20',
  '70',
  '2',
  'MAY 2015'
)
on conflict (rno, subcode) do nothing;
```

Again: the `on conflict` will only work if you have a unique constraint (or index) on those two columns.

---

Unrelated, but:

you should specify each constant value with a literal matching the underlying data type. `'20'` is a character constant, `20` would be a number. Ìf intm, extm and crd re numbers, don't provide character values. Also if `resultdate` is a `date` column `'MAY 2015'` won't work either.

Comment: thanq so much you saved my day it worked with that i have a doubt i want do some action if the conflict arise where am i supposed to write that code

Comment: @HimajaSidhireddi: no code required. The `do nothing` causes the offending row to be silently be ignored and the row will not be inserted.

Comment: but i need to write i have 2 tables demi and supply .if a record exists in demi i need to update record in demi if only current value in crd is greater than  previous one .then copy previous record to supply so i need to write code for all this and will "on conflict insert" work? plz help

Comment: You have not mentioned anything about a second table in your question. Changing the scope of the question after you have received an answer is considered rude. It's better to ask  a **new** question with the additional requirements (you can reference this one). Or at least [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43309819/edit) your current question to reflect the extended scope of your problem.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience  i'm posting a qstn for first tym  i'm going to ask a new qstn and thanq it worked for update and do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how

```
end where not exists(SELECT * FROM demi WHERE rn0 ='13JG105A0' AND subcode='RT22058')
```

got into your code, but the whole thing is suspicious what do you even want that to do?

Comment: i'm trying to insert a particular record into db if and only if there exists no other record with same rno and subject code columns